# parsing input through char array to char pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, shell, pointers

So, the goal here is to set up a linux shell so that a user-input is processed in to how many arguments and the arguments themselves - ultimately to fork and execvp. I am having issues getting my commands to seperate. I need to count them, which is working fine, and separate the commands in to a char pointer array that they may be called. I had one method going where it would work if you had just one command, but if you did two it flipped out. I trashed it and went back to this method as I felt I was closer.. Anyhow.. This is standard operating system --homework--. I'm not looking for an answer, just some guidance or example to work from. Ultimately, if this method I'm currently using will not operate through execvp I'd appreciate just knowing that up front, too..

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int count_args(char *str);
void get_args(char* in_args, char** out_args);

int main() {
string my_path;
char user_input[1064];
char *args[64];
my_path = getenv("PATH");

while (1) {
    cout << ">> ";
    cin.getline(user_input, 1064);

    int num_words = count_args(user_input);

    get_args(user_input, args);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_words; ++i) {
        cout << num_words << " " << args[i] << endl;
    }
}

return 0;
}

int count_args(char *str) {
int cnt = 0, space;

while (*str) {
    if (*str == ' ' || *str == '\n' || *str == '\t') {
        space = 0;
    } else if (space == 0) {
        space = 1;
        ++cnt;
    }
    ++str;
}

return cnt;
}

void get_args(char* in_args, char** out_args) {
char str[64];
int pos = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    str[i] = '0';
}

while (*in_args) {
    if (*in_args != ' ' || *in_args != '\n' || *in_args != '\t') {
        str[pos] = *in_args;
        ++pos;
    } else {
        memcpy(out_args, str, pos);
        pos = 0;
    }
    *in_args = *in_args + 1;
}
}
```

Comment: you are aware of main(int argc, char ** argv) I assume?

Comment: yea but I thought that was for when they execute the file only. So, in turn ,they'd have to re-execute everytime. In this, they are just prompted for the next set of commands. Never the less, I don't know how to utilize argc and argv either. I havent actually had a class where they use variables passed into main from the execution of the file

Comment: have a look at [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) for stepping through tokens in a string.

Comment: I suggest - read the documentation on memcpy(), it may reveal your basic misunderstanding.  also, brush up on how c/c++ allocation of memory,  lastly, think carefully about what you've got with your declaration of args, and how you are using it

Comment: do you know how to use your debugger, investing a little time to learn it will help a lot in understanding what the program is doing

Comment: Firstly, Nathan it's working much better now. It's getting them in to the args how I need it but it keeps having a segmentation issue. I'll investigate further but you have solved this.

To Les, thanks for trying. I do misunderstand memcpy. Also, debugging sucks on Linux haha. I loved it in visual studio. I could step through everything and see what I needed. CodeBlocks seems to lack what I am use to and I havent see anything else (I'm not use to Linux)

Comment: What do you believe the last line of your while loop does?  Look again.